# How use sql in Teradata with Aster database?

Tags: sql, teradata, aster

Currenly I use Teradata Studio, and I want to use table in Aster, it's possible to create dblinks or other configuration to call tables from Aster database to Teradata database into Teradata Studio?.

Thanks.

Comment: Teradata offers a product called QueryGrid that allows you to establish foreign servers that accomplish what you are describing. As far as I know, Teradata Studio cannot facilitate this directly. You may be able to use Teradata Studio to move data between the platforms. For example, export data from Aster and use Data Loader in Teradata Studio to load a Teradata table.

Comment: This is an oldie, but it popped back to the top of the queue due to the edit. So... with the new Vantage platform where Aster type stuff has been rolled into the new architecture, what you are wanting to do here would be possible. You submit SQL into Teradata and it can ship the interim result set over to your advanced analytics nodes (MLEs with the Aster type functionality) do the processing, and ship the data back to the database and then returned in a result set to your sql client. Of course, you have to be up on the new Vantage platform though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Aster you will be having a SQL-MR function name load_to_teradata you can use it to load tables from aster to teradatadb